# Mule Echo component changes the message

Tags: echo, mule

The Mule Echo component is meant to output the current message to the console. As far as the documentation goes the Echo component shouldn't change the message in any way. However I have noticed that it does have an effect on the message seemingly similar to an Object to String component.

Is this expected or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected.

Use the `<logger>` message processor, which is a replacement of the obsolete Echo Component, and which doesn't log the message payload by default, i.e. leaving it intact by default.