# mule esb No listener found for request : (GET) /echo

Tags: mule, mule-studio

When trying a simple example of a mulesoft tutorial, I don't have the result as explained in the tutorial

tutorial link:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.3/configuring-an-endpoint

video link:

http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/getting-started-with-mule-free-training-videos-tutorials/

Flow:

[image]

I have configured the HTTP Element like this:

[image]

and for the Listner:

[image]

but when I try in the browser to get:

http://localhost:8081/echo

this did not display /echo

it displays this message in the console:

```
INFO  2016-12-13 12:34:22,652 [[echo2].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpListenerRegistry: No listener found for request: (GET)/echo
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I would have thought that you would need to set the base path on the Http Listener to /echo

Comment: I already tested that, but no result as well

Comment: when adding a logger between the HTTP and the echo its says the payload is null.

Comment: As you are doing a GET request, that would be expected for a request. Usually only POST & PUTs have payloads for the request

Comment: The video link,  says that from the browser when you try http://localhost:8081/echo , you are doing a get request, witch is true right ?

Comment: The Echo component was deprecated in Mule 3.5 and, as already stated in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295940/mule-echo-component-changes-the-message), is was replaced by the Logger component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I created the flow witch shows the `Echo component` in action in the latest mule version (3.8)

The Echo component is used to log the message and return the payload as result

Here is the working flow:

[image]

So I have added the transformer `Set Payload` to be able to set the payload with the received value and set it as following:

[image]

**For the Echo component we have just to add it:**

[image]

**The HTTP Endpoint:**

[image]

**Result when tested with Firefox:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

The Echo component is deprecated since `mule ver. 3.5` but **still work**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referring to 3.3 version document / video tutorial. Seems you are using 3.8 version mule run time and latest any point studio, so refer to document for 3.8 version. May be features might have changed in newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your application and it is because you are missing the **path=/echo** attribute on your http:listener component.

Please compare my working configurations.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="echo-testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/echo" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="Inside #[flow.name] with payload #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since echo component display the content of payload.Hence you are not able to see any thing in log.Also in the path instead of "/" you have to use "/*".
Let me know the outcome of it.